# CSS - IE7 does not render textarea boxes and some drop down fields correctly/completely

Tags: php, html, css

I have been researching this issue for a couple of weeks now.  Note in the image attached.  **IE7** and only **IE7** does not render the textarea fields completely/correctly within my php application.  This also happens with some drop down fields as you can see in the attached.  The right border will not display for some reason and a potential client that has IE7 and can't/won't upgrade will not be able to use my app if this issue continues.

I've found several other rendering issues while surfing; there was a mention of using zoom, but that had no effect, another mentioned adding padding, still no effect. Nothing that I found really addresses this particular issue/bug.

**Are there any CSS experts out there that could provide any insight on this one.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Image of issue[image]

This is an auto-generating web form.

**Here is the php code that would create the textarea field :**

```
case FIELD_TEXT_AREA:
    $fieldHtml = inputOrText($mode, "textarea",
                             $field->getValue(), 
                             array("id"=>$field->getId(),
                             "class"=>"valuetext",
                             "name"=>$field->getId(),
                             "rows"=>"3","cols"=>"60",
                             $jsFunctionCalls),
                             array("class"=>"valuetext"));
```

**and here is the result source code:**

```
               <td valign='top'></td>
           </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr id="field-4446">
  <td width='30%' valign='top' align='left' class='labeltext'>Text Area :</td>
  <td width='70%' align='left'>
     <table border='0' style='table-layout:fixed'>
         <tr>
             <td>
               <textarea id="4446" 
                         class="valuetext" 
                         name="4446" rows="3" 
                         cols="60" 0="" > 
               </textarea>
             </td>
```

Comment: Can you provide a URL where we can see your app and examine the code/css etc?

Comment: Although the image is a good asset to your question, we cannot really work out the problem with such a brief snippet of code

Comment: I wish I could give out the url, but it's a client's site, so don't want to use my job.  Since this is an IE7 issue, I was hoping someone knew so of the fixes/hackes to remedy some of it's display issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable reason is that the cells containing the input box and the textarea have some fixed width set on them so that it is a little less than needed for the fields. And probably the cells have `overflow: hidden`. The fields are then truncated on the right. The width mismatch may well depend on browser, as it as affected by the box model and things like that.

If you experimentally set `textarea, input { overflow: visible !important }` in CSS, you should see how much they overflow. As the overall layout probably cannot or should not be changed at this point, it is probably best to reduce the width settings for the fields. The details depend on how the widths have now been set. Note that setting the widths to 100% may cause a problem like this rather than fix it. The width should be a few pixels smaller than the width of the cell.

Comment: Thank you Jukka.  Let me test out a few of your suggestions

Comment: Hi Jukka - I found that IE7 actually had a web developer tool of sorts.  I dl it and saw a few possible things, but one was table-layout:fixed.  I changed that to "auto".  It renders correctly now in IE7 and doesn't seem to have any adverse effect in the other browsers, thus far.  Do you by chance now of anything related to table-layout: **auto** vs **fixed** that I should be aware of?

Comment: Setting `table-layout: fixed` can surely cause problems, since it sets column widths in a rigid manner, no matter what their width requirements are. Changing the value to `auto` is equivalent to removing the setting, as `auto` is the default. And `auto` is normally best, except when you really need to fix column widths and you are prepared to handle the consequences.

Comment: I moved the change in last night, so far no complaints from the other clients, so I think I am good.  Will let it marinate a few more days before I breathe a true sigh of relief.  Thanks again for your help!!